# Laravel migration error when creating a new migration with same name that I deleted

Tags: laravel

Why do laravel has this error failed to open stream: no such file or directory.

I just deleted the 'makers' table and make a new one using php artisan make:migration command but now it has that error.  Please help me

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to run `composer dump-autoload` before running the migration.

In your terminal run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to delete migration from `migrations` table. For check run below given mysql query, If you found, remove it and try.

```
SELECT * FROM `migrations` WHERE migration = 'YOURMIGRATIONNAME';
```

This should work for you..!